# Coloured view in vim editor not working in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, command-line, vim

My Vim editor version `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:19:52)`

When I open a file(shell script, etc) with it, all the text are on same color. It's not user friendly. How can I solved it?

I tried with adding `syntax on` in `~/.vimrc` file. but no use. It says

> E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: syntax on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get install vim`. By default Ubuntu comes with `vim-minimal` (which does not have syntax highlighting).